# Include libraries in iOS library project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am writing an iOS library which depends on some other open-source libraries. Apparently it is not possible to have two classes with the same name, so it is possible that the library compiles, and a project that potentially could use it compiles as well, but they do not work well together (at the linking phase).

The library is targeted at a large audience, so I can not make any assumptions on whether these developers will be importing the same libraries or not, or if they might be using a different, incompatible version of the same libraries.

I have been looking around but couldn't find any clear solution to my problem (maybe there isn't). So far I am thinking of these options:

- Inform the users that X libraries are already included in the project, so they do not include them as well. This means they can not use a different version of X libraries.
- As a refined version of the first one, use CocoaPods, so dependencies are resolved automatically. Still has the disadvantage that two versions of the library can not coexist.
- Import and rename all classes my library depends on, prefixing them, so the names don't conflict with the original ones. This is tedious work, but more importantly, has the disadvantage that I would not be able to pull/push code from/to the original library, as the code would change too much. Still seems to me the best option from the user perspective.

Can you think of a better idea? I'm pretty new to library projects, so maybe there is something obvious I am missing.

We're still not decided whether to distribute in binary or source code form. If there is a reason to choose one or another I would also like to hear your opinion.

Comment: are you thinking of distributing the source or binary?

Comment: I added that to the description, thanks hooleyhoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was faced with this problem I choose your third option and prefixed the dependent classes within my library. The reason you might want to consider doing this rather than relying on the user to import the others would be that you can guarantee compatibility and you don't have to worry about versions of who you depend on.

Comment: I ended up doing this, thank you. I still wonder if there's a better option, but it looks like not.

Answer (score 0):

First point -

> Inform the users that X libraries are already included in the project,
>   so they do not include them as well

so you have a static library **Foolib.a**, it has a 3rd party dependency **Barlib.a**, in order for Foolib to build, Foolib's `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` must be set to the path of Barlib's public headers. No more.

If you are distributing your source code you can use CocoaPods (this is a good way to go), or you can add Barlib's repository as a git submodule (or whatever for your choice of VCS) of your repository and hard code the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` to that path, or you can require that your user grabs their own Barlib and manually edits `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` to the correct path (if you go the CocoaPods or submodule route the user can easily do this as well, so has more options).

**Nothing from Barlib is 'in' your project.**

On the other hand, if you are distributing a binary for your user to link into their app you must specify in your instructions that *Foolib* requires *Barlib* to be linked into the app. Instructions for how to get hold of Barlib would be nice.

**Nothing from Barlib is 'in' your project or compiled into your library.**

Second Point -

> use CocoaPods, so dependencies are resolved automatically. Still has
>   the disadvantage that two versions of the library can not coexist

Two versions of the same library in one App is impossible, but the situation where the end user already requires Barlib 3.0, wants to use your Foolib, but Foolib requires Barlib 4.0 doesn't have to ever arise - It is up to you the developer. You can be generous and support multiple versions of Barlib (i.e. all Foolib needs to work is a Barlib1.0, Barlib2.0, Barlib3.0 OR Barlib4.0 linked into the app - similar to writing an app that supports iOS5 and iOS6) or, you can be opinionated and require a specific version, and if the user is already requiring a different version of Barlib, tough luck, they will have to change their code if they want to use your library.

Third point -

> Import and rename all classes my library depends on, prefixing them,
>   so the names don't conflict with the original one

This is just too terrible for me to consider at the moment. Sorry.

Nothing from Barlib is ever 'in' your project or compiled into your library. You don't distribute any copy of Barlib - either linked into your binary or as source code.